# Allow maximum n documents in the result with different filters

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "active"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query will only allow documents with `status = "active"`. But I want to allow maximum of 3 documents to have `status = "paused"` as well alongside those active ones.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution may be using msearch endpoint

```
GET /_msearch
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"status": "paused" }}]}},"size":3}
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"status": "active" }}]}}}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I want.